# How to store ImageMagick convert info: in a variable in php

Tags: php, image-processing, imagemagick

**Overview:**

I am using `convert result.jpg -deskew 40 -format "%[deskew:angle]" info:` in terminal to get the information about deskew angle for an image. and I get result as `-0.111906`. I know how to save this value in a variable while using command line but now I would like to do the same in my php script.

**Problem:**

How to store the information given from convert command into a variable in php?

**My trial:**

```
$diskew = exec('convert result.jpg -deskew 40 -format "%[deskew:angle]" info:');

echo $diskew;//returns nothing(I am expecting -0.111906 here)
```

**Command line solution:**

```
    diskew = `convert result.jpg -deskew 40 -format "%[deskew:angle]" info:`;

    echo $diskew;//returns -0.11196(Perfect but my problem is how to do it in php)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
exec('convert result.jpg -deskew 40 -format "%[deskew:angle]" info:', $diskew, $ret_var );
```

look the second parameter, that's the exec ouput str.

Comment: I do have the extension. My worry is about the syntax, the code that I can use to store a variable.

Comment: `exec('convert result.jpg -deskew 40 -format "%[deskew:angle]" info:', $diskew, $ret_var );`

Answer (score 0):

I was so stupid. I did use `.jpg` instead of `.png` which I should have used for the png image I am having.

Posting it as an answer, so that no one else repeats my mistake.

Comment: Just a note, it may be easier just to use the php Imagick extension:

http://php.net/imagick

Comment: yes.I do have that, I used that in some cases such as annotating my images etc but mostly I end up using ImageMagick as they have a better documentation than iMagick extension for php.